# db.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 could not read ok from ADB Server

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am getting the above error when I start my android studio. I tried reinstalling the studio, but it didn't worked either. Also I tried running the adb.exe from command prompt but it gives me the same error.

'C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

14:46   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

14:46   could not read ok from ADB Server

14:46   * failed to start daemon

14:46   error: cannot connect to daemon

*Another thing I observed is, I'm not able to see the package details of Android SDK Platform tools and Android SDK Tools in Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools section**

I'm new to android, I've tried executing all the possible solutions available on internet. Please shed some light on the problem. Thank you.